# Bookmarklet - Fetch ID from URL and put it in clipboard

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I'm trying for a while now to get started with JQuery, but again I'm stuck with regex.
What I want to achieve is this:

- Bookmarklet that uses JQuery or JS
- Bookmarklet looks at current URL I'm at
- Check If URL contains an ID like this: '1.1188651' (1digit+period+7digits)
- If Check OK then copy ID in clipboard or display in new window

Can this be done?
I'm very thankful for your help.

Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegEx to test the url:

```
/\d\.\d{7}/.test(sUrl);
```

Also see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qc6bn/).

To also get the id:

```
var sId = /\d\.\d{7}/.exec(sUrl);
if (sId !== null) {
    alert(sId);
}
```

Also see my [second jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qc6bn/1/).

=== UPDATE ===

So the bookmarklet could be:

```
javascript:if((sId=/\d\.\d{7}/.exec(window.location.href))!==null){alert(sId);}
```

`javascript:` prefix for the bookmarklet;
`window.location.href` is the current url;
`sId=/\d\.\d{7}/.exec(...)` saves the regex result in `sId`;
`if(>regex<!==null) {...}` checks if regex has matched;
`alert(sId);` shows the id in a "new window".

=== UPDATE 2 ===

If the format is `12345678` (eight digits) and you want a `.` after the first digit, you can use following bookmarklet:

```
javascript:if((aId=/(\d)(\d{7})/.exec(window.location.href))!==null){alert(aId[1]+'.'+aId[2]);}
```

Comment: Do you have a magic trick that displays the fetched ID in this format? 1.2344566
All I need is a dot after the first number.
AND I need a major learning course for regex. These things are powerful!

Comment: In which format is the id displayed at the moment? Only ids with a dot at the second place are matching the regex.

Comment: Right now the format is 12345678 and the output should be 1.2345678

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to copy data to clipboard.

```
funcation CopyToClipboard(myHerf){
        if (window.clipboardData) {
            var ok = window.clipboardData.setData("Text", myHerf);
            if (ok) {
                Alert("Copy OK,Ctrl+V Paste");
                    }
            else {
                 alert("Sorry,IE Only!");
                 }
         }
    }
```

Comment: for Clipboard API use see: https://stackabuse.com/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript-with-the-clipboard-api/